# Unwanted logs using log4r on RoR 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, log4r

I'm using RoR 4.1.12 and log4r gem for formatting the log. I thought that everything is OK, but if I want to change the log level it has no influence at all.

I have the following `config/log4r_init.rb`:

```
require 'log4r'
require 'log4r/yamlconfigurator'
require 'log4r/outputter/fileoutputter'
require 'log4r/outputter/datefileoutputter'

# The problem is that Rails 4.2 (not sure about other versions at the moment) expects a method
# on the logger called formatter(). Log4r, however, defines formatter() on each outputter of 
# the logger (i.e. so that each outputter can have a different format). 
# We could monkey-patch it like this
Log4r::Logger.class_eval do
  def formatter
    # Give it the first formatter we have?
    outputters[0].formatter if outputters.any?
  end
end

# log4r.yml configuration is expected to be in the same directory as this file. 
log4r_config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/log4r.yml"))).result)
Log4r::YamlConfigurator.decode_yaml(log4r_config['log4r_config'])

V2p0::Application.config.logger = Log4r::Logger[Rails.env]
```

and the following `config/log4r.yml`:

```
log4r_config:
  loggers:
    - name : development
      level : WARN
      additive : 'false'
      trace : 'true'
      outputters:
      - standard_plus_trace_log_outputter
      - stderr_outputter
    - name : test
      level : DEBUG
      additive : 'false'
      trace : 'true'
      outputters:
      - standard_plus_trace_log_outputter
    - name : staging
      level : INFO
      additive : 'false'
      trace : 'true'
      outputters:
      - standard_plus_trace_log_outputter
      - stderr_outputter
    - name : production
      level : INFO
      additive : 'false'
      trace : 'true'
      outputters:
      - standard_plus_trace_log_outputter
      - stderr_outputter

  outputters:
    - type : StderrOutputter
     name : stderr_outputter
      level : INFO
      formatter:
        date_pattern: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        pattern : "[SXS] [%d] PID:%p %t %l %m"
        type : PatternFormatter
    - type : FileOutputter
      name : standard_log_outputter
      trunc : 'false'
      filename : <%= "#{Rails.root}/log/#{Rails.env}.log" %>
      formatter :
        date_pattern: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'
        pattern : "[SXS] [%d] %l %m"
        type : PatternFormatter
    - type : FileOutputter
      name : standard_plus_trace_log_outputter
      trunc : 'false'
      filename : <%= "#{Rails.root}/log/#{Rails.env}.log" %>
      formatter :
        date_pattern: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'
        pattern : "[SXS] [%d] %t %l %m"
        type : PatternFormatter
```

Even if the level is WARN on development mode, I see a lot of similar log messages on the error output:

```
[SXS] [2017-12-19 14:11:32] PID:947 /home/ntibor/.bundle/ruby/2.2.0/rails-9bfb9f2c3b8b/activesupport/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:93:in `info' INFO   Rendered shared/_common_scripts.html.erb (5.6ms)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: what unwanted logs you want to hide?

Comment: For example the one in the example: "INFO Rendered....", which is an INFO level message appearing in the log, however the development level is set the WARNING.